# How to stop pagination in listview when duplicate json data found which is come from API

Tags: android, listview

```
I have API which provides country list,every page have 10 countries.Up to 13th page API provides unique country list,but if we call after 14th,15th,16 page and so on ,which provides 13th page data only.Here when I scroll down my listview after 13th page,I am getting duplicate values that is 14th page data is being added to my list. How to stop pagination in listview?
```

---

```
<pre> This is 12th page </pre>
```

`enter code here
        [
          {
            "id": 221,
            "country": "Trinidad And Tobago",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 222,
            "country": "Tunisia",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 223,
            "country": "Turkey",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 224,
            "country": "Turkmenistan",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 225,
            "country": "Turks And Caicos Islands",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 226,
            "country": "Tuvalu",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 227,
            "country": "Uganda",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 228,
            "country": "Ukraine",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 229,
            "country": "United Arab Emirates",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 230,
            "country": "United Kingdom",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 231,
            "country": "United States",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 232,
            "country": "United States Minor Outlying Islands",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 233,
            "country": "Uruguay",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 234,
            "country": "Uzbekistan",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 235,
            "country": "Vanuatu",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 236,
            "country": "Vatican City State (Holy See)",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 237,
            "country": "Venezuela",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 238,
            "country": "Vietnam",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 239,
            "country": "Virgin Islands (British)",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 240,
            "country": "Virgin Islands (US)",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          }
        ]`
    
     13th page.(last page):
    

    
        `[
          {
            "id": 241,
            "country": "Wallis And Futuna Islands",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 242,
            "country": "Western Sahara",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 243,
            "country": "Yemen",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 244,
            "country": "Yugoslavia",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 245,
            "country": "Zambia",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 246,
            "country": "Zimbabwe",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          }
        ]`
        
    
    Then 14th page.(**See duplicates are being come now**)
    
        
        `[
          {
            "id": 241,
            "country": "Wallis And Futuna Islands",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 242,
            "country": "Western Sahara",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 243,
            "country": "Yemen",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 244,
            "country": "Yugoslavia",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 245,
            "country": "Zambia",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          },
          {
            "id": 246,
            "country": "Zimbabwe",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 11:28:33"
          }
        ]`

---

```
When scroll down in listview upto 13th page,all countries are come normally,after 14th page API still gives more data but which are duplicate the duplicates are belongs to 13th page only.
```

```
enter code

 hereprivate void mLoadData() {

        mUtil.getBaseClassService(this,"").getContry(currentPage,new Callback<JsonArray>() {
            @Override
            public void success(JsonArray jsonArray, Response response) {
            try {
                if (jsonArrayList.size() > 2) {
                    if (jsonArrayList.get(jsonArrayList.size() - 2).equals(jsonArrayList.get(jsonArrayList.size() - 1))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "success: jsonarray eaqual" + "equal");
                        mDuplicateValuesStarts = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                jsonArrayList.add(jsonArray);
                if(!mDuplicateValuesStarts) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                        CountriesModel countriesModel = new CountriesModel();
                        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                        countriesModel.setCountry(jsonObject.get("country").getAsString());
                        countriesModel.setId(jsonObject.get("id").getAsInt());
                        countriesModelList.add(countriesModel);
//                        countryList.add(jsonObject.get("country").getAsString());
                    }
//                Log.d(TAG, "success: before"+countriesModelList.size());
                    filetDummyContriesListFromAPI(countriesModelList);
//                Log.d(TAG, "success: after"+countriesModelList.size());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listview_ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "success: "+e.getMessage());
            }

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Internet connection error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "failure: retro"+error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (loading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                        loading = false;
                        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                        currentPage++;
                    }
                }
                if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
                    // but you can call any function here.
//                    new LoadGigsTask().execute(currentPage + 1);
                    if(!mDuplicateValuesStarts)
                    mLoadData();
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
 private void filetDummyContriesListFromAPI(List<CountriesModel> countriesModelList) {
//        Log.d(TAG, "filetDummyContriesListFromAPI: before2"+countriesModelList.size());

        TreeSet<CountriesModel> myset = new TreeSet<>(countriesModelList);
//        Log.d(TAG, "filetDummyContriesListFromAPI: after"+countriesModelList.size());

        this.countriesModelList.clear();
        this.countriesModelList.addAll(myset);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be handled on the server side and ensure there are no duplicates

Comment: But I must handle in client side.

Comment: Then you need to deserialize the json into a list of objects and remove the duplicates first

Comment: yes I did it,results fine,but still I am getting few duplicates.I want at least no  duplicates in my list.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend with which property of the object is unique ie identity property of the object, identity could be unique but other properties redundant .In this case it's the id and if you correctly remove duplicates before displaying, then you should not have this problem